# How to localized app tile title in app list?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to localize the app tile title in windows phone 8 app .For this I am using msdn sample and implemented all of functionality according to msdn sample but only neutral app title is display.it does not support another language. While app all data  is localized.In app list some other app title is changed according to different language.

Comment: Are you following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must create a resource-only DLL for each display language that your application targets. Here have a look at this: http://www.cnblogs.com/promise-7/articles/2270760.html